# Is there a cleaner way to choose part of a tuple using a variable?

Tags: swift, tuples

I'm working on a game where several parameters of the characters are determined by the difficulty level. For example the size of the boss will increase from easy to normal to hard. I know I can do this with if statements and switch statements that are nested or lined up on top of each other for a thousand lines of code (I'll probably end up with over dozen parameters for almost 20 bosses for the 3 difficulty levels (pending the addition of any more...), but I wanted to do it in an easier to read, more concise way using tuples. I'm thinking it should be easy but I'm really struggling to make it work as the error states that the tuple has no member difficultyLevel:

```
let difficultyLevel = 0 //0 for easy, 1 for normal, 2 for hard
let bossOneScale = (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat) = (0.3, 0.6, 0.9)
bossScale = bossOneScale.difficultyLevel
```

and then I reference the bossScale when the enemy is created in the main part of the code, which would have the correct size based on the passed difficultyLevel value.

I know I could do this easily by using:

```
switch bossNumber {
case 1: 
    if difficultyLevel = .easy {bossScale = 0.3)
    else if difficultyLevel == .normal {bossScale = 0.6)
    else if difficultyLevel == .hard {bossScale = 0.9)
case 2:...
```

I just thought it would be easier to read given how long it's going to get by using tuples but I'm not sure how to subscript the tuple to get the value I want using a variable...

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to achieve. Are you trying to map an enum value like `.easy` to a float? What exactly does each member of a tuple represent (i.e. what the meaning behind `0.3` vs `0.6` vs `0.9` for a particular boss character). And what does `bossNumber` mean? Is this an character ID of some kind?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you are exactly right that I'm assigning a number to the difficulty level and trying to use that to pull the scale out of the tuple for the boss. So on the easy level the boss will take up about a third of the screen, on normal 2/3s and on hard almost the whole screen.

Comment: And each boss character can have its own scale? Like boss #2 can have 0.1, 0.5, 0.7? In any case, why can you not create an object that represents each boss, and a func that takes an enum of difficulty and returns a float? Or use an enum with associated values? I think we could give you a better answer if you explained (with code) how you want to use this, and where the complexity comes from

Comment: I'm not accusing you New Dev, but thanks for the down vote whoever decided that they didn't like my question, this is why I don't ask many questions here...I wasn't looking for someone to write the whole game for me, I had a specific question about using a variable to subscript a tuple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few peripheral things you can do with tuples and enums for reference including named tuples (so you can reference as `bossOneScale.easy`) and enums with associated values (aka storing a value inside of an enum: `let damageMultiplier = .easy(0.3)`). But those don't seem like they'll help here since you still have to switch to access all of them.

If you want to be able to access values with an int variable why not just use a good ol' array:

```swift
let difficultyLevel = 0 //0 for easy, 1 for normal, 2 for hard
let bossOneScale: [CGFloat] = [0.3, 0.6, 0.9]
bossScale = bossOneScale[difficultyLevel]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this sort of thing:

```
enum Difficulty: Int {
    case easy
    case medium
    case hard
}

func bossOneScale(difficulty: Difficulty) -> Double {
    return Double(difficulty.rawValue + 1) * 0.3
}
```

The point here is that if you have other bosses with other scales, those scales, too, can be expressed as functions. It may even be that these scaling functions can all be moved off to become *methods* of boss *types*.

Moreover, if all the scaling functions work the same way, you can have a factory that generates them:

```
enum Difficulty: Int {
    case easy
    case medium
    case hard
}

func scaler(offset: Double, multiplier: Double) -> (Difficulty) -> Double {
    return { difficulty in
        (Double(difficulty.rawValue) + offset) * multiplier
    }
}
```

So for example your boss one scale function can be generated like this:

```
 let bossOneScale = scaler(offset: 1.0, multiplier: 0.3)
```

Let's test it:

```
bossOneScale(.easy) // 0.3
bossOneScale(.medium) // 0.6
// you get the idea
```